# Wordpress Contact Form 7 - How to get correct phone number?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am using contact form on wordpress website and it has phone number field. The issue I am having is even wrong number with 13, 14, character is also getting submitted.

1. How can I restrict it to submit only 10 digit numbers?
2. Is there any way I can add country code flag and code number by default someone filling the form.

Kindly suggest something, although I am not a coder but will give a try.

Answer (score 0):

1. I am not recommending you to restrict phone to 10 digits, because in some countries phone numbers are longer, even longer if you add country code at the beginning.

If characters (not numbers) are being submitted, make sure that you used [tel] shortcode instead of [text] or [textarea] for phone number input field.

2. I recommend [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/country-phone-field-contact-form-7/) to add country flag and country code input filed to your contact form. After installing, two new shortcodes will appear: "Phone Numer" and "Country Drop-Down". Read documentation of plugin for more info.